# I want to run a function with an iteration of rows as parameters, python

Tags: python, pandas, distribution, prediction, poisson

I have a function that takes the argument home and away as two soccer teams, then applys the poisson distribution (with previous historical information), and makes a prediction of the home and away expected goals. The code is the following:

```
    def predictMatchScore(home, away):
if home in eplTeamStrength.index and away in eplTeamStrength.index:
    lambdH = eplTeamStrength.at[home,'HomeAttack'] * eplTeamStrength.at[away,'AwayDefense'] * overallHomeScored
    lambdA = eplTeamStrength.at[away,'AwayAttack'] * eplTeamStrength.at[home,'HomeDefense'] * overallAwayScored
    probH, probA, probT = 0, 0, 0  # Probability of Home win(H), Away win(A) or Tie(T) 
    for X in range(0,11):
        for Y in range(0, 11):
            p = poisson.pmf(X, lambdH) * poisson.pmf(Y, lambdA)
            if X == Y:
                probT += p
            elif X > Y:
                probH += p
            else:
                probA += p
    scoreH = 3 * probH + probT
    scoreA = 3 * probA + probT
    return (scoreH, scoreA)
else:
    return (0, 0)
```

The outcomes looks like this:

```
    predictMatchScore('Bayern Munich','Dortmund')
    3.2456343, 2.3212355
```

This means that based on previous historical information, the poisson distribution calculates the score of this particular match as shown above.

The thing is that i would like to calculate the effectiveness of this distribution. How? Well I have a dataframe that has 25000 matches, home and away, and of course the result has already been given. But what I want to acheive, is to place all the matches in the predictMatchScore function; and end up with two new columns in my dataframe, for example:

HomeTeam//AwayTeam//Real score home//Real score away//PredictdHome//PredAw

Bayern//Dortmund//3//2//3.24//2.32

Schalke04//Augsburg//2//1//3.45//1.09

Frankfurt//Bayer04//1//0//2.34//0.56
...

And so on, predicting all the matches in my historical dataframe, then to compare the predictions with the real results.

So to wrap it up, I would like the function to take a lot of parameters, and have a results outcome for every match.

I hope I made myself clear. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, i posted it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: What's the question

Comment: guys i edited my post, hope you get it, im not sure if i explained it right haha

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
     H_R=[]
     A_R=[]
     for index, row in season_16_17.iterrows():
         home, away = row['HomeTeam'], row['AwayTeam']
         sH, sA = predictMatchScore(home, away)
         H_R.append(round(sH,2))
         A_R.append(round(sA,2))
```